# combine list with multiple dicts in a list to a single list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list with multiple dicts in a list. I want to combine the list in to one. In here, i am using for loop to merge but unable to do it. Help me with some solutions. the multiple list  in the list of dicts in the datas can be increased during execution. so i am using for loop to get it

Here's the sample code:

```
datas = [
[{'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'tirunelveli', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '1'}, 
{'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'nagerkoil', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '2'}, 
{'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'tuticorin', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '3'}, 
{'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'madurai', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '4'},
{'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'chennai', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '5'}],
[{'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'palakad', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '6'}, 
{'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'guruvayor', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '7'}, 
{'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'kolikodu', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '8'}, 
{'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'kottayam', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '9'}, 
{'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'idukki', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '10'}],
[]
]
d = []
def throttle(d):
    if data !=[]:
        d.append(data)
        print(d)
    else:
        print("no data")   

for data in datas:
    throttle(data)
```

output i got:

```
[{'city': 'tirunelveli', 'serial': '1', 'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu'}, {'city': 'nagerkoil', 'serial': '2', 'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu'}, {'city': 'tuticorin', 'serial': '3', 'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu'}, {'city': 'madurai', 'serial': '4', 'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu'}, {'city': 'chennai', 'serial': '5', 'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu'}, [...]]
[{'city': 'palakad', 'serial': '6', 'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala'}, {'city': 'guruvayor', 'serial': '7', 'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala'}, {'city': 'kolikodu', 'serial': '8', 'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala'}, {'city': 'kottayam', 'serial': '9', 'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala'}, {'city': 'idukki', 'serial': '10', 'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala'}, [...]]
no data
```

Required output:

```
[{'city': 'tirunelveli', 'serial': '1', 'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu'}, {'city': 'nagerkoil', 'serial': '2', 'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu'}, {'city': 'tuticorin', 'serial': '3', 'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu'}, {'city': 'madurai', 'serial': '4', 'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu'}, {'city': 'chennai', 'serial': '5', 'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu'},{'city': 'palakad', 'serial': '6', 'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala'}, {'city': 'guruvayor', 'serial': '7', 'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala'}, {'city': 'kolikodu', 'serial': '8', 'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala'}, {'city': 'kottayam', 'serial': '9', 'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala'}, {'city': 'idukki', 'serial': '10', 'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala'}]
no data
```

Comment: Are you trying to flatten a list? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason you can not get what you want is that you have nested list in `datas`, so you should extend the list, not append.

you can try this:

```
d = []
for data in datas:
    if data:
        d += data
```

or use `filter` and `reduce`, `filter` is used to filter empty list, and `reduce` to combine.

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
d = list(reduce(operator.__add__, filter(None, datas)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
print([x for li in datas for x in li])
```

Output:

```
 [{'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'tirunelveli', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '1'}, {'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'nagerkoil', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '2'}, {'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'tuticorin', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '3'}, {'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'madurai', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '4'}, {'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'chennai', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '5'}, {'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'palakad', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '6'}, {'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'guruvayor', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '7'}, {'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'kolikodu', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '8'}, {'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'kottayam', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '9'}, {'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'idukki', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '10'}]
```

Comment: This doesn't give the result as desired by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a good use case for [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(datas))
[{'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'tirunelveli', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '1'}, {'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'nagerkoil', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '2'}, {'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'tuticorin', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '3'}, {'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'madurai', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '4'}, {'state': 'tamil nadu', 'city': 'chennai', 'haps': 'hap0', 'serial': '5'}, {'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'palakad', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '6'}, {'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'guruvayor', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '7'}, {'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'kolikodu', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '8'}, {'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'kottayam', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '9'}, {'state': 'kerala', 'city': 'idukki', 'haps': 'hap1', 'serial': '10'}]
```